# Objective-C: Method's return value and Completion block, how are they executed?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I make an photography app in iPhone and I have these 3 classes: ViewController, CaptureManager, and ImgProcessor.

ViewController:

```
-(IBAction)takePic:(id)sender{
     images = [captureManager takeMultipleImagesWithCompletion:^{

          //Some UI related code..

          [imgProcessor process:images];
     }];
}
```

CaptureManager:

```
-(NSArray *)takeMultipleImagesWithCompletion:^(void)completionHandler{

     // take picture codes...

     completionHandler();

     return arrayOfImagesTaken;
}
```

So far it works as desired: `imgProcessor` processes the *images* taken by `captureManager`. But I don't quite get the idea how this works. Bcos I called completionHandler before I return the array of images taken. How did this code executed? Is there a better solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to return the value images. You can pass it as an argument for the cmpletionHandler block.

```
-(void)takeMultipleImagesWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *images))completionHnadler{

     // take picture codes...
     completionHnadler(arrayOfImagesTaken);
}
```

You can call it like this :

```
-(IBAction)takePic:(id)sender{
      [captureManager takeMultipleImagesWithCompletion:^(NSArray *images){
           [imgProcessor process:images];
     }];
}
```

How it works ?

Here the block is used as a callback, it defines the code to be executed when a task completes. When the takeMultipleImagesWithCompletion is finished running, the block completionHnadler will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `takeMultipleImagesWithCompletion` executes the completion block synchronously, it doesn't need to take a completion block. It can just return the `arrayOfImagesTaken` and the caller can do whatever it wants with it.